# $\lim_{x\to 0}\lfloor{\frac{\sin x}{x}}\rfloor$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $\quad\displaystyle\Big\lfloor\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\Big\rfloor-\lim_{x\to 0}\Big\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\Big\rfloor\;\;??$

My working: $1-0=1$.

Comment: Correct. ${}{}$

Comment: I think its correct as $sinx/x < 1$ so $ [sinx/x]$ = 0 and $[lim_{x \rightarrow 0} sinx/x] = lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 1 = 1$

Comment: Am I the only one who is confused? How did you arrive at $1-0$ ? I see no difference between the two functions inside of the floor function

Comment: For positive $x$, $0\leq \sin{x} < x$, thus $0\leq \frac{\sin{x}}{x}<1$ and $\left \lfloor \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \right \rfloor=0$ ... it should be $0$ in this case. It can not be $1$, otherwise you will obtain a contradiction of the form $\forall \varepsilon > 0 ... 1 = \left|1 - \left \lfloor \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \right \rfloor\right| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: At Zacky  I think it was a mistake .  I  Fixed that  in a way coherent with  the following..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x>0$, it holds $\sin x<x$, so
$$
0<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1 \tag{*}
$$
For $x<0$
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{\sin(-x)}{-x}
$$
so the inequality (*) holds for every $x\ne0$. Hence
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor=0
$$
for $x\ne0$ and the limit is $0$.

Since $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, the floor is $1$. Thus you're correct
$$
\left\lfloor\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor-
\lim_{x\to0}\left\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor=1-0=1
$$